# How to read WebSockets with Chrome extensions or apps?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, websocket, google-chrome-app

I'm developing an extension for a game but I need your help. I need to know how to read WebSockets registers with Chrome extensions/apps?

[image: How to]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why did you dim that text? It's still readable...

Comment: I know, someone answer plz?